# Firebase Find by specific field in url

Tags: firebase

I want to find by specific field in give URL of firebase

I have seen you can find by following program:

```
new Firebase("https://examples-sql-queries.firebaseio.com/user")
.startAt('kato@firebase.com')
.endAt('kato@firebase.com')
.once('value', function(snap) {
console.log('accounts matching email address', snap.val())
});
```

but here we are not mentioning that find email address which matches'kato@firebase.com'. I want to mention that find only if **email** address matches

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do a search of Firebase records, you'll need to pull in some other tool like ElasticSearch. See this blog post for more details: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-01-02-queries-part-two.html